# AAM for HTTP My site a requirement?

Tags: https, mysites

I had an existing farm that was run on HTTP and we upgraded the farm to be all SSL enabled.  I had updated the URLs for all web applications to be https and used URL rewrite rules on all IIS servers to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS.

This morning I tried changing the AAM for the My Sites collection to be https only.  When I did this, I got 401 unauthorized errors when visiting the One Drive or viewing the Newsfeed for a my site.  If I add back in the http binding, it works.

Is there any way I can remove the requirement of having an AAM listed for an HTTP site?  Do I have to update the Work Management service somehow to only go to HTTPS?

Comment: did you updated the mySite host location, from user profile?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Bingo!  That was it.

Comment: i just added it as an answer, so please mark it so that other gets benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySite. You have to make changes two places.

1. Update the MySite Host in the User Profile Services Settings.
2. Update AAM for the MYSite.